# TimeZone.IsInvalidTime not catching invalid time caused by dst for Egypt in 2010

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

**This is a corner case scenario.**

I'm working on a fix to convert invalid local time's to UTC. In localtimezones, due to daylight saving time(dst), certain periods cannot be converted to UTC. TimeZone.IsInvalidTime() can be used to identify such datatime values, given the correct timezone.

In Egypt, DST was changed 4 times the year in 2010 (due to Ramadan). The second such conversion doesn't seem to be detected by IsInvalidTime().

***edit***
The TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(), which is what I use to actually convert it to UTC, converts these values to UTC. A wrong conversion, but conversion all the same.

Anybody come across this, any suggestions as to override this?

Comment: Have a look here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2297272 and not sure if you need [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2543367)

Comment: It seems to fix the calendar and outlook but doesn't provide a help for the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows time zone database is notoriously bad with accurately reflecting historical changes to time zone rules.  Use an IANA/Olson time zone database instead.  See the [TimeZone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more info on the different databases.

For .Net, the best solution is to use [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).  It fully implements the IANA/Olson database.  You would use the `Africa/Cairo` time zone, which accurately reflects all of the historical changes.

Comment: It's not just the historical side of things which is problematic here - I believe the Windows time zone representation can't support more than 2 transitions per year at all.